# Facebook share dialog as alternative to publish_actions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook seems to have discontinued the publish_actions permission recently so that apps can't post for a user anymore:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.1/page/feed#publish

The recommended alternative is to use the share dialog. Is there any way that the share dialog can be configured so that it would post to pages (that I don't own) instead of posting to the users feed?

Comment: Why would you post on pages that you don't own?

Comment: @WizKid: Let's say I had a webshop that suggests to post a question/review/complaint to the manufacturers facebook page

Comment: That would only work for manufacturers that let users post to their pages in the first place. And no, it is not possible using either the Share or the Feed dialog.

Comment: Then go and manually do that. Absolutely no reason to spam pages in an automated way

Comment: @CBroe: Thanks that answers my question

Comment: @WizKid: Essentially this would be users doing it manually. Just from within another site. But I understand even that is something that one could argue about. Anyway, I was mainly seeking for confirmation that this is not possible

Comment: We have a use case where it makes total sense to post in behalf of a user. Very large companies stream videos through our service. We have an online clipping tool for their videos that will allow them to create clips and post them to social sites like YouTube, Twitter and (formerly) Facebook. Customers are now complaining they can't publish to their FB accounts since FB turned it off. These companies may have a FB page and now with this new method FB recommends, employees must make sure they are logged into the company FB page and not their personal FB before publishing.